# connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi_dev.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running django application with uwsgi + Nginx with crontab command given below

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile /path/to/lock_file -- uwsgi --close-on-exec -s /path/to/socket_file --chdir /path/to/project/settings/folder/ --pp .. -w project_name.wsgi -C666 -p 3 -H /path/to/virtualenv/folder/ 1>> /path/to/log_file 2>> /path/to/error_log
```

but nginx error log file shows the error

> *83 connect() to unix:///path/to/socket_file failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server:
>   localhost, request: "GET /auth/status/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///path/to/socket_file:", host: "xx.xxx.xx.xxx",
>   referrer: "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/"

Answer (score 0):

Check if .sock file is created:

```
ls /path/to/socket_file
```

If it is created, check permissions:

```
ls -l /path/to/socket_file
```

Check where is the socket file created, may be due to chdir command, it has created somewhere else.

```
lsof | grep socket_file
```

If they are fine, can you share ngnix config details?

It's simple and better to use a file to supply configuration parameters.
Sample uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]

print = -------------------------------------------------
print = Hello UWSGI is ready to start...
print = -------------------------------------------------

# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /path/to/chdir/

#Application's wsgi file/module
module          = wsgi:application

# process-related settings
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 8

socket          = /path/to/myuwsgi.sock
pidfile         = /opt/uwsgi/mywsgi.pid
chmod-socket = 660
logto2 = /log/path/uwsgi.log
```

to apply these while uwsgi is starting up, do

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

Alternatively, to direct logs to specific file:

```
uwsgi <your other paramerters> --logto2 /log/path/uwsgi.log
```

Comment: When I run, uwsgi --socket /path/to/socket_file --module project_name.wsgi , a new socket is created, (uwsgi --socket /path/to/socket_file --module project_name.wsgi --chmod-socket=666, if permission denied), and we kill this process and try to run the cronjob with the crated socket it throws the above error (nginx configured with the socket above created), if we remove the socket and run the cronjob, it throws the error "connect() to unix:///path/to/socket_file failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream"

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I run the cronjob,  `2019/11/19 10:50:46 [crit] 26111#26111: *6 connect() to unix:///path/to/socket_file failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/status/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///path/to/socket_file:", host: "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", referrer: "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/"`

Comment: How are you killing uwsgi process? kill -9 <uwsgi_process>? 

Try with graceful shutdown : kill -HUP <uwsgi_pid>
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 -f <socket_name>`

Comment: After you run the cronjob,

Make sure uwsgi is running.
`ps -eaf | grep uwsgi `

Make sure .sock file is created by uwsgi
`ls -l <path/to/socket_file>`


Then, connect with nginx

NOTE: Do not kill by -9 or manually remove .sock file.

Comment: I'm getting the out put for **ps -eaf | grep uwsgi** as `devadmin  29060  34555  0 11:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi`, with uwsgi in red color, but the socket file is not created....

Comment: That means, **uwsgi** is not runnnig, it has listed grep command only. Before you run nginx, see uwsgi logs, if it has actually started by cron.

Comment: Log for cronjob, just redirect logs to a file in shell script. For uwsgi logs, I have updated answer on how to use config file and do   `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`

Comment: when I run the `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` the socket is created and able to run the server...and log file also created...

Comment: can you tell me what is meant by the `processes = 8`  in the ini file??Is that have any effect on number of users???

Comment: No, it's number of uwsgi child processes. To handle more traffic.

Comment: I added `/usr/local/bin/uswsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ --uid root --gid root` in rc.local file which is mentioned in docs but still the server is not starting

Comment: I found the issue, actually the location of uwsgi is in another repository, so the cronjob can't locate the uwsgi. Once I gave the correct location the server start running...Thanks for spending your valuable time....

Comment: But if I use the **rc.local** file the server is not working, any idea about this???

Comment: My server is too slow and unable to connect, I don't know why? once I connected mysql server was down, but some how I managed to up the mysql server, but when I run the application in cronjob again it become too slow and unable to connect through ssh and in browser also...What might be the issue??